# Listing inside align environment doesn't work

Tags: math-mode, listings

I found a very specific formatting error: when I use `lstinline[mathescape]` inside an `align` environment, some of the basic math formatting like subscripting stops working. It does however work in e.g., an `equation` environment. The strange thing is that when I don't load the `syntax` package, this bug does not occur.

A **complete minimal example** that reproduces the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{syntax}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
e_1 \mapsto \lstinline[mathescape]|Stream.of($e_1$)|
\end{align*}

\begin{equation*}
e_1 \mapsto \lstinline[mathescape]|Stream.of($e_1$)|
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, the subscription inside the align envirnoment doesn't work.

[image: bug illustration]

Is there a way to resolve this error cleanly? What is causing it?

---

**EDIT** Based on @UlrikFisher's comment, I could find a workaround specifically for the underscore. Unfortunately, this workaround does not work for other macros. Here is a more complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[nounderscore]{syntax}
\usepackage[shorthand]{semantic}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
e_1 \mapsto \lstinline[mathescape]+Stream.of($|[e_1|]$)+
\end{align*}

\begin{equation*}
e_1 \mapsto \lstinline[mathescape]+Stream.of($|[e_1|]$)+
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image: full bug]

Comment: the body of an align environment is essentially the argument of an internal command so you can not use verbatim-like commands such as \lstinline. This is not really related to the syntax package.

Comment: you could use `\usepackage[nounderscore]{syntax}`. Then the package will not redefine the underscore, something which seems to disturb listings.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle okay, good to know. Still, it must be somehow (indirectly) related to the syntax package, because when I leave `\usepackage{syntax}` everything works fine.

Comment: or rather you got lucky, it basically doesn't work but some characters don't need the verbatim catcode changes so sort of work anyway. but with the syntax package loaded `_` is made active not its usual math subscript meaning, so you get less lucky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The body of an AMS alignment is essentially the argument of an internal command (so the body can be used twice as part of the alignment measuring)  This means that no verb-like commands work.

Sometimes you get lucky and the argument to lstinline doesn't need any special catcode changes so that the command appears to work, but basically it can not work in this setting.

Loading teh `syntax` package apparently globally redefined `_` with a catcode 13 definition and listings can not revert this inside an `align`

You can set the text in a box before starting the alignment

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{syntax}

\newbox\mybox
\begin{document}


\setbox\mybox\hbox{{\lstinline[mathescape]|Stream.of($e_1$)|}}
\begin{align*}
e_1 \mapsto \usebox{\mybox}
\end{align*}

\begin{equation*}
e_1 \mapsto \lstinline[mathescape]|Stream.of($e_1$)|
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```